# GAE throwing error running under Eclipse on Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

When I run GAE `dev_appserver.py` from Eclipse (Oxygen) an exception **is** thrown. When I run `dev_appserver.py` from a cmd line (not run as admin) an exception **is not** thrown.

```
The GAE exception thrown:

File "C:\Users\c\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261721\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_net_command_factory_xml.py", line 197, in make_thread_stack_str

File "C:\Users\c\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261721\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_net_command_factory_xml.py", line 170, in _iter_visible_frames_info

File "C:\Users\c\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261721\pysrc\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 489, in _original_file_to_client

File "C:\Users\c\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261721\pysrc\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 196, in _get_path_with_real_case

File "C:\Users\c\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261721\pysrc\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 159, in _resolve_listing

File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\stubs.py", line 309, in __call__

raise self._error_class(errno.EACCES, 'path not accessible', path)

OSError: [Errno 13] path not accessible: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
```

Eclipse did run with older version of GAE but not with `GoogleAppEngine-1.9.85`

`dev_appserver.py` runs without this error from the CMD line and from Visual Code.

This is one of those nasty config errors. Perhaps no one has come across this exact scenario, but anyone offer any advice on what to try?